# array bucket sort in C

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am trying to read list of numbers from txt file and then sort them with Bucket sort.
so here is my code:

```
void bucketSort(int array[],int *n)
{
    int i, j;  
    int count[*n]; 
    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        count[i] = 0;

    for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
        (count[array[i]])++;

    for (i = 0, j = 0; i < *n; i++)  
        for(; count[i] > 0; (count[i])--)
            array[j++] = i; 
}   

int main(int brArg,char *arg[])
{

    FILE *ulaz;
    ulaz = fopen(arg[1], "r");

    int array[100];
    int i=0,j,k,n;


      while(fscanf(ulaz, "%d", &array[i])!=EOF)i++;

    fclose(ulaz);    
    n=i;
    for (j = 0; j<i; j++)
    {
        printf("Broj: %d\n", array[j]);
    }

    BucketSort(array,&n); 
    for (k = 0; k<i; k++)
        printf("%d \n", array[i]);   


    return 0;
}
```

There are no errors in code,but when i call my function instead of sorted array i get array length random numbers(example: 2 3 5 4,after sorting i get 124520 124520 124520 124520 or some other random number) since i am a beginner,could someone help me with my code and what i did wrong? (sorry for bad english)

Comment: Your code works if `i` is greater than all the values of the array `array`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Cool Guy correctly pointed out you have issues with memory access but on top of it the code does not sort anything. First you should read how [Bucket Sort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort) actually works.

In general:

- You divide the input data among buckets by some criteria that guarantees that the buckets will not mess up the input order
- Sort each bucket either using some other sorting method or recursively with bucket sort
- Concatenate the sorted data (this is why the first point has the restriction of not messing up the input order)

Here is an example of your original code, I tried to adjust it as little as possible you it is easier for you to understand. This code divides a predefined input array among 3 buckets by range:

- [-infinity][-1] -> first bucket
- [0;10] -> second bucket
- [11;infinity] -> third bucket

then performs Quicksort on each bucket and concatenates the result. I hope this helps to understand how this algorithm works.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct bucket 
{
    int count;
    int* values;
};

int compareIntegers(const void* first, const void* second)
{
    int a = *((int*)first), b =  *((int*)second);
    if (a == b)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    else if (a < b)
    {
        return -1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

void bucketSort(int array[],int n)
{
    struct bucket buckets[3];
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        buckets[i].count = 0;
        buckets[i].values = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    }
    // Divide the unsorted elements among 3 buckets
    // < 0    : first
    // 0 - 10 : second
    // > 10   : third
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < 0)
        {
            buckets[0].values[buckets[0].count++] = array[i];
        }
        else if (array[i] > 10)
        {
            buckets[2].values[buckets[2].count++] = array[i];
        }
        else
        {
            buckets[1].values[buckets[1].count++] = array[i];
        }
    }
    for (k = 0, i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        // Use Quicksort to sort each bucket individually
        qsort(buckets[i].values, buckets[i].count, sizeof(int), &compareIntegers);
        for (j = 0; j < buckets[i].count; j++)
        {
            array[k + j] = buckets[i].values[j];
        }
        k += buckets[i].count;
        free(buckets[i].values);
    }
}

int main(int brArg,char *arg[]) {

    int array[100] = { -5, -9, 1000, 1, -10, 0, 2, 3, 5, 4, 1234, 7 };
    int i = 12,j,k,n;

    n=i;
    for (j = 0; j<i; j++)
    {
        printf("Broj: %d\n", array[j]);
    }

    bucketSort(array, n); 
    for (k = 0; k<i; k++)
        printf("%d \n", array[k]);   


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your help guys! I really appreciate both of your answers thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your code exhibits Undefined Behavior as you try to write into memory location which are not owned by your program.

```
for (i = 0; i < *n; i++)
    (count[array[i]])++;
```

The above loop is causing the problem. You say that `i` is 4 which means that `*n` is also 4 and `array` contains `2 3 5 4`. In the above code,`count` is an array of `*n` elements(in this case 4 elements) and the valid indices for the array are `count[0]`,`count[1]`,`count[2]` and `count[3]`. Doing

```
count[array[i]]
```

when `i` is zero is okay as it is same as `count[2]`. This is the same when `i` is 1 as it would be `count[3]` . After that ,when `i` is 4 and 5,`count[4]` and `count[5]` are wrong as you try to write to a invalid memory location.

Also,your code dosen't sort the values.